# Why is there difference in move behavior between String and &String?

Tags: rust

Example 1
`ee` and `ff` are references located on stack, and according to my understanding if there is no Copy trait defined on a type, it will do simple bit-wise copy (I guess there is no Copy trait on &String). There is no move here as bits are just copied, so `ee` and `ff` are accessible throughout the function.

```
fn main() {
    let dd = String::from("jellooooo");
    let ee = &dd;
    let ff = ee;

    println!("{}", *ee);    
}
```

Example 2
Here we cannot access `dd01`. I understand that since String has both the stack and heap allocations, and no Copy trait, `ee01` contains  bit-wise copy of the stack part.

```
fn main() {     
    let dd01 = String::from("belloooo");
    let ee01 = dd01;
    
    println!("{}", dd01);
}
```

My question is how does the compiler know that String has the heap and stack allocations but &String doesn't? Or if I am getting all of this wrong, why in the first example there is no problem?

Comment: The first example is fine, as [_all immutable references are `Copy`_](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#impl-Copy-for-%26T)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to heap allocations but to being `Copy`. Shared references (`&String`) are `Copy`, so we can use both variables. `String` is not `Copy`, so we can only use the last variable. The *reason* `String` is not `Copy` is because it has a heap allocation, but this is not something the compiler knows, it is something that the authors of libstd know.

Comment: I am a bit confused with the answer, because first you say that it's not  related to heap allocations but later you mention "because it has heap allocations". At the same time, I don't think that std got anything to do with this .

Comment: @whowhenhow From the compiler point of view, it doesn't know about heap allocation. The question is whether the type is `Copy` or not. But we as the programmers know that the reason `String` is not `Copy` is because it contains a heap allocation and thus can't be trivially copied. This is the reason the authors of libstd (where `String` lives) didn't make it `Copy`.

Comment: you mean if there is no Copy  on a type the compiler assumes move?

Comment: @whowhenhow Yes.